# Probability of pulling out socks.

Tags: probability

A math task, where I've gotten mixed answers has occupied my mind, it goes like this.

A boy has his sister organize 7 pairs of socks into 2 different drawers.

Electricity goes out and the boy has to take out a pair of identical socks, what are the odds and why?

In my head, if you take a sock out from the first drawer, it doesn't affect the odds of taking out the identical pair from the 2nd one, so it should be 1/7, but people are saying it's 1/49, cause it matters which sock he takes from the first drawer, the question I have is, what is the correct answer and why?

Comment: If the question refers to the probability of getting an undefined pair of identical socks, the answer is indeed $\frac{1}{7}.$ Only if the question refers to the probability of getting a specific pair of socks, the answer is $\frac{1}{49}.$

Comment: The seven pairs are distinguishable from each other? and from each pair, one sock goes into one drawer, and the other sock goes into the other drawer?

Comment: @jvdhooft So if the pair of socks is defined, it's 1 49th, but if it's not defined it is 1 7th okay.  At GerryMyerson they are distinguishable from each other and pairs are separated in to two different drawers.

Comment: @DariusUscins Assuming that socks are distinguishable (e.g., by color), and that socks belonging to the same pair are put in different drawers, the above is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned taking out one pair, not a specific one. So it does not matter which one you take from the 1st drawer. You still have a chance of 1:7 to get a matching one.

If let's say the pairs would have different colors and you'd need to get the red pair, in that case there would be an initial 1:7 to get a red from the 1st drawer combined with the same probability to get the red from the 2nd drawer, so in total it would make the probability 1:49 go get the specific pair.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered.

If you have sock pairs split up and put in to two different drawers, and they are distinguishable from one another then you have two answers.

1. If a defined pair is required to be taken out it is 1/49th,
2. If you just need to get a pair out it is 1/7th